# A message saying "confusing indentation" and "assign return value to new variable"

Tags: java, return, indentation

I have been working on this project, the project runs fine, but it shows "confusing indentation" and "assign return value to new variable" warnings and I have no idea what it's about. This is the line with the warning:

**System.out.printf("The sum of the squares: %.0f\n", tsquee);**

The following is the complete project. Thanks!

```
    double n = 0;
    while (n < 25)
    {
        n = n + 1;
        if (n > 25) 
            break;

        System.out.printf("%3.0f%15.2f%16.2f%17.2f%15.2f\n", n, Math.cbrt(n), Math.sqrt(n), Math.pow(n, 3), Math.pow(n, 2));

    }

    {
        double tsquee = 0.0, tsqueer = 0.0;
        int csq = 0, ccube = 0;

        for (n = 0; n <= 25; n++)
            tsquee += Math.pow(n, 2); tsqueer += Math.sqrt(n);

        for (n = 0; n <= 25; n++)    
        if (Math.pow(n, 2) > 250)
        {    
            csq++;
        }    
        else if (Math.pow(n, 3) > 2000)
        {    
            ccube++;
        }



        System.out.printf("The sum of the squares: %.0f\n", tsquee);
        System.out.printf("The sum of the square roots: %.2f\n", tsqueer);
        System.out.println("The number of squares greater than 250: " + csq);
        System.out.println("The number of cubes greater than 2000: " + ccube);
    }


}
```

Kay

Comment: The warning is quite specific. Your indentation is very, very confusing -- for example, look at your `if/else` in the `for`. It looks like it's on the same level, and therefore occurs after the `for`, not inside.

Comment: It's a good idea to use `{` and `}` whenever you use `for`, `while`, `do`, `if` or `else`.  Omitting them can lead to errors.  I think  every Java programmer has fallen into this trap at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The "confusing indentation" warning is likely because the set of curly braces that start after the while loop and go to the end are not needed. Also, your for loop syntax is incorrect. I think what you want is this:

```
for (n = 0; n <= 25; n++)
{
    if (Math.pow(n, 2) > 250)
    {    
        csq++;
    }    
    else if (Math.pow(n, 3) > 2000)
    {    
        ccube++;
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure. You need to enclose the code you wanted to loop through inside curly braces just like you've done with your while loop.

Also, since your two for loops have identical bounds and conditions, you could combine them into one for loop:

```
for (n = 0; n <= 25; n++)
{
    tsquee += Math.pow(n, 2);
    tsqueer += Math.sqrt(n); // I would also put these on separate lines

    if (Math.pow(n, 2) > 250)
    {    
        csq++;
    }    
    else if (Math.pow(n, 3) > 2000)
    {    
        ccube++;
    }
}
```